# Outlook gives this weird error on my UserForm

Tags: vba, outlook

> ```
> Set olMessage = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
> olMessage.To = strEmailTo
> olMessage.CC = strEmailCC
> olMessage.Subject = strSubject
> olMessage.Body = strBody
> olMessage.Importance = olImportanceHigh
> olMessage.Sensitivity = olConfidential
> olMessage.Display ' Line With Error
> ```

The above code is inside a button on my User Form. The error says

> A dialog box is open. Close it and try again

When I place either code alone in a macro it works fine and opens a new email etc, but when I set the macro to load the userform and place the code under a commandbutton, it gives an error dialog box:

```
Run-time error '2147467259 (80004005)'

A dialog box is open. Close it and try again.
```

Outlook is already open and the macro is on the toolbar.

Module 1 (code)

```
sub email() 
Load userform3
userform3.show
end sub
```

loads my menu fine

Comment: Have you tried closing the open dialog box?? o_0  A macro cannot execute in such a state, while the application is waiting for a response from you.  Also, are you running this VBA from a different application (e.g., Excel, etc.)

Comment: There is no Dialog box that is open.

Comment: This is running *entirely* from Outlook? Or are you automating Outlook from another application.

Comment: Its running entirely in Outlook

Comment: See my answer below for two solutions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running this entirely from Outlook (and not using another application to automate the sending of an email, i.e., from Excel or PowerPoint, etc.) then this is the problem:

You are displaying your `UserForm3` modally.  This means that the application is essentially on hold, while the form is displayed.

To avoid this error, display it modelessly, like:

```
userform3.show vbModeless
```

**Note:** This allows the user to interact with the Outlook Application while the form is displayed. This may not be desired, in which case I think you will have to close/hide the userform before you display the email. Just add `Unload Me` preceding the `.Display` command:

```
Set olMessage = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
olMessage.To = strEmailTo
olMessage.CC = strEmailCC
olMessage.Subject = strSubject
olMessage.Body = strBody
olMessage.Importance = olImportanceHigh
olMessage.Sensitivity = olConfidential
Unload Me
olMessage.Display ' Line With Error
```

Both above methods avoid the error. Which one you elect to use depends on your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could simply hide the form before executing the code:

```
Private Sub cmdButton_Click()

UserForm3.hide

    Set olMessage = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    olMessage.To = strEmailTo
    olMessage.CC = strEmailCC
    olMessage.Subject = strSubject
    olMessage.Body = strBody
    olMessage.Importance = olImportanceHigh
    olMessage.Sensitivity = olConfidential
    olMessage.Display ' Line With Error

End Sub
```

Hiding the UserForm bypasses the "Open Dialog Box" error and preserves user input. It's also simpler than dealing with VB modalities and prevents unwanted behaviour.